# Why is the solution to multiply rather than dividing by 10,000?

Tags: pandas, multiplication, division

Hi I was working on Datacamp and there was a problem where you needed to find the number of homeless individuals per 10,000. I was unable to understand why the website answer only involves multiplying by 10,000 instead of dividing by 10,000. Could anyone explain to me the rationale to make sense of it?

Please see the following instruction/comment with Datacamp solution:

```
# Create indiv_per_10k col as homeless individuals per 10k state pop
homelessness["indiv_per_10k"] = 10000 * homelessness['individuals'] / homelessness['state_pop']
```

Before checking the solution, I tried the following, but it was rejected:

```
homelessness["indiv_per_10k"] = homelessness['individuals'] / (homelessness['state_pop'] * 10000)
```

Answer (score 2):

`homelessness['individuals'] / homelessness['state_pop']` is the proportion of homeless individuals in your state population.

It is a value between 0 and 1 (inclusive).

You can multiply this proportion by any number to find the *proportion per that number*.

E.g. You could multiply by 100 to get *percent*.

But you've been asked to get homeless individuals *per 10k*, so you need to multiply by 10,000.

---

Because of [Order of Operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations),

`10000 * homelessness['individuals'] / homelessness['state_pop']`

is the same as

`(homelessness['individuals'] / homelessness['state_pop']) * 10000`

but is NOT the same as

`homelessness['individuals'] / (homelessness['state_pop'] * 10000)`

In this final sum, we're multiplying the *population* by 10000, rather than the *proportion of homeless individuals in the state population*.

So, we would end up with a tiny number between 0 and 1 representing the number of homeless individuals in a much larger population.

Comment: For example, there are `171,500` homeless people in California (estimation by [HUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Department_of_Housing_and_Urban_Development) from this Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homelessness_in_California)) and California has a population of `39,185,605` (from this Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California)). So the proportion of homeless individuals in California's population is `171,500 / 39,185,605 = 0.00438` which is the same as `0.438 %` or `0.00438 * 10000 = 43.8` homeless individuals per 10k.

Answer (score 1):

Karl's answer is the correct one, but to add some meat onto the bones, with a dataframe you can play around with:

```
import pandas as pd

# in the example dataframe, California has a population of 10,000 people, and 20 homeless individuals, so we know the rate per 10,000 people must be 20
homelessness = pd.DataFrame({
    "state": ["CA"],
    "state_pop" : [10000],
    "individuals": [20]
    })

# this is the correct answer, because the numerator is multiplied by 10,000
10000 * homelessness['individuals'] / homelessness['state_pop'] # 20

# this is the wrong answer, because you are multiplying the denominator instead
homelessness['individuals'] / (homelessness['state_pop'] * 10000) # 2.000000e-07 (a.k.a 0.0000002)
```

For more information, [here's a video on Khan Academy on rates](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qGTYSAeLTOE).